# Searching mysql database for duplicate user_id using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to do something that I think should be pretty basic, but I'm not having any luck.  I want to create a unique user id for each user.  I have the code written for creating a random, 7-digit number, and I need to just check the number against the database to see if that user id already exists (unlikely since I'm using a 7-digit number, but I have to check anyway).

Here's the relevant portion of the code:

```
 <?php

require("config.inc.php");

$test_number = "1234567"; 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id ='$test_number'");

echo $test_number; 

if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0){
   echo "\n number already exists.";
}else{
   echo "\n number not found"; 
}

?>
```

I'm just using `test number` as a placeholder.  I've manually added the number `1234567` to my database, but every time I run the code, the second prong of the if-statement gets called, so the out put is always "1234567 number not found" even though that number does exist for a user in my database.

The `require ("config.inc.php")` line works because I have other .php files that use that same file and connect to the database just fine, so I don't think it's a connection issue.

Comment: make sure you're indeed using the `mysql_` API to connect with. The column's type and length are unknown. If it's an `int` then try removing the quotes for `"1234567"` and `'$test_number'` and that there is no leading/trailing whitespace in the row(s). You can also try `>0` rather than `!= 0`. You may also need to pass db connection variable to the query. I.e.: `WHERE user_id ='$test_number'", $con);` if your require has db variables set for it.

Comment: Try that ^ and ping me if you want. I won't be able to provide you with any magical here, sorry. That's the best I can think of; good luck. I have to go now.

Comment: Thanks... the column is INT(11).  I tried removing the quotes, but still not working... not sure what you mean about the whitespace.  I switched to >0 rather than !=0, but still not working.  I'll look into the db connection issue, but as I said, the `config.inc.php` file works for my login and register scripts, so I don't think that's it.

Comment: Still not working... anyone???

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon this... it's working now.  The problem was my config.inc.php file.  It looks like it was not connecting to the database, for some reason.  Still haven't figured out why, but that was the problem.  When I used `$mysqlConnection = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);` instead, it started working.

Answer (score -1):

Please try with code

```html
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';

 mysql_select_db('tsg_userlogin_dev', $link) or die('Could not select database.');

$test_number = "88888"; 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT EmployeeId FROM tsguser WHERE EmployeeId ='$test_number'");

echo $test_number; 

if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0){
   echo "\n number already exists.";
}else{
   echo "\n number not found"; 
}
```